# 2nd PHP Doesn't Display Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I've been stuck on this problem last night.

Basically the webpage runs the first PHP segment which displays a search table and the second PHP displayed on the page is within an aria-hidden modal that is supposed to display another search table.

I'm still very new to PHP but was wondering why this is happening, I've only included the body segment for the HTML file. This is also running Bootstrap and there aren't any errors that I know of that could be stopping this.

Lastly, I have tested in the 2nd PHP segment simply echoing out a static table I built and it worked, so the PHP segment is for sure being executed, just the table isn't be snagged.

**Quick notice**
I have ran the code for grab_sql_promo_all in the first PHP segment and it has worked, there aren't any issues regarding the SQL grabbing the DB contents.

HTML

```
<body style="background: #36465d;">
<!-- WRAPPER -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="index.html">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="items.html">Items</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="promotions.html">Promotions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="adEvent.html">Ad Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->
    <!-- LEFT SIDEBAR -->
    <nav id="left-sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div id="left-sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <ul id="main-menu" class="metismenu">
              <center><li style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Items</b></li></center>
             <li name="newItem" id="newItem"><a href="items.html">Add Item</a></li>
             <li name="searchItem" id="searchItem" class="active"><a href="items.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Items</a></li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Screen Reader -->
            <h1 class="sr-only">Item Search</h1>
            <!-- Item Manipulation Panel -->
 <!--  TABLE TO RETURN DATA TO  -->

                    <div id="searchResults" class="container">
                     <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;"><b>Item Search Results:</b></h2>
                        <center>
                        <table class="table" id="table">
                                                    <!-- Listing Search -->
                                                            <?php
                                                                include('php/new_search.php');
                                                                $data = grab_sql($_POST['itemNumber'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['department']);
                                                                echo "<thead><tr>";
                                                                for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($data); $i++) {
                                                                    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($data, $i);
                                                                    echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
                                                                }
                                                                echo "<th>Edit Item</th><th>Add Promotion</th>
                                                                </tr></thead>";

                                                                echo "<tbody>";

                                                                // Print the data
                                                                $increment = 0;
                                                                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)) {
                                                                    $bounce_back = 0;
                                                                    echo "<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='#itemDetailModal'>";
                                                                    foreach($row as $_column) {
                                                                        echo "<td><p><div name='item$increment' id='item$increment'>{$_column}</div></p></td>";
                                                                        $bounce_back++;
                                                                        $increment++;
                                                                    }
                                                                    // should readjust back to itemNumber designated index value
                                                                    // then simply iterate 6 times in evaluateData to grab all fields
                                                                    $adjust=$increment - $bounce_back;
                                                                    echo "<td><button style='padding: 10px 10px;' onclick='evaluateData($adjust)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#itemEditModal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></td>
                                            <td><button style='padding: 10px 10px;' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#selectPromotionModal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>

                                                                    </tr>";
                                                                }

                                                                echo "</tbody>";
                                                             ?>

                        </table>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <!-- END TABLE CONTENT -->

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- END WRAPPER -->

<!-- START OF MODAL PROMOTION PROMPTS -->

<!-- Item Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="itemEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="itemEditModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="itemEditModal" style="bottom-padding: 10px;"><b>Edit Item:</b></h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="bottom-padding: 10px;" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Update Item Form -->
                <!-- Used to display the alerts -->
                    <div id="alertboxitemadd" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in" style="display: none; color: black; white-space: pre-wrap;">

                    </div>
            <form name="itemUpdateForm" id="itemUpdateForm" onsubmit="return addItemValidation();" method="POST" action="php/new_update_item.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                             <h5>Item Number:</h5>
                             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Item Number" name="itemNumber" id="itemNumber" type="text" readonly>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                     <h5>Item Description:</h5>
                                 <textarea rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description" name="description" id="description" type="text"></textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                     <h5>Item Category:</h5>
                                     <select style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" class="form-control" id="category" title="category" name="category">
                         <option style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0);" value="" disabled selected>Item Category</option>
                         <option value="ACCESSORIES/FOOTWEAR">ACCESSORIES/FOOTWEAR</option>
                         <option value="BASIC APPAREL">BASIC APPAREL</option>
                         <option value="FOOD CONVENIENCE">FOOD CONVENIENCE</option>
                         <option value="FOOD GROCERY">FOOD GROCERY</option>
                                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                     <h5>Department Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</h5>
                                     <select style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" class="form-control" id="department" title="department" name="department">
                         <option style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0);" value="" disabled selected>Department Name</option>
                         <option value="ACCESSORIES">ACCESSORIES</option>
                         <option value="FOOTWEAR">FOOTWEAR</option>
                         <option value="CHILDRENS BASICS">CHILDRENS BASICS</option>
                         <option value="LADIES BASICS">LADIES BASICS</option>
                         <option value="MENS BASIC">MENS BASIC</option>
                         <option value="CANDY">CANDY</option>
                         <option value="REFRIGERATED">REFRIGERATED</option>
                         <option value="COOKIES/CRACKERS">COOKIES/CRACKERS</option>
                         <option value="GROCERY">GROCERY</option>
                         <option value="SALTY SNACKS">SALTY SNACKS</option>
                                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                     <h5>Purchase Cost:</h5>
                         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Purchase Cost" name="cost" id="cost" type="text" value="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                     <h5>Full Retail Price:</h5>
                         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Retail Price" name="price" id="price" type="text" value="">
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectPromotionModal">Select Promotion</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"value="Close">
                        <input class="btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
                 </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- END OF MODAL PROMOTION PROMPTS -->

        <!--  RETURN ALL PROMOTIONS MODAL START -->

<div class="modal fade" id="selectPromotionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="selectPromotionModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="selectPromotionModal" style="bottom-padding: 10px;"><b>Select Promotions:</b></h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="bottom-padding: 10px;" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <center>
            <table class="table" id="selectPromoTable">
            <!-- Listing Search -->
            <?php
                require('php/new_search.php');
                $promo_data = grab_sql_promo_all();
                echo "<thead><tr>";
                for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($promo_data); $i++) {
                    $field_infos = mysql_fetch_field($promo_data, $i);
                    echo "<th>{$field_infos->name}</th>";
                }
                echo "<th>Add Promotion</th>
                </tr></thead>";
             ?>

            </table>
            </center>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>-->Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--  RETURN ALL PROMOTIONS MODAL END -->
</body>
```

PHP new_search.php

```
<?php
  require('server_connection.inc');

  function grab_sql_promo_all() {
    connect_to_db(DB_SERVER, DB_UN, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
    $searchStatement = "select * from Promotion";
    $result = mysql_query($searchStatement);

    return $result;
  }

  function grab_sql_promo($promo_name, $promo_type, $promo_off) {
    connect_to_db(DB_SERVER, DB_UN, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);

    $appendString="";

    if($promo_name != '')     $appendString .= "Name='$promo_name' AND ";
    if($promo_type != '')     $appendString .= "PromoType='$promo_type' AND ";
    if($promo_off != '')      $appendString .= "AmountOff='$promo_off' AND ";

    $appendString = str_lreplace("AND","",$appendString);
    // create the statement
    $searchStatement = "select * from Promotion where $appendString";

    $result = mysql_query($searchStatement);
    $message = "";

    if(!$result) {
      $message = "Error in updating Item: $item_number: ". mysql_error();
    } else {
      $message = "Data for Item: $item_number.";
    }

    return $result;

  }

  function grab_sql($item_number, $item_description, $item_category, $department_name) {
    connect_to_db(DB_SERVER, DB_UN, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
    // append string
    $appendString="";

    // setup string
    if($item_number != '')      $appendString .= "ItemNumber='$item_number' AND ";
    if($item_description != '') $appendString .= "ItemDescription='$item_description' AND ";
    if($item_category != '') $appendString .= "Category='$item_category' AND ";
    if($department_name != '') $appendString .= "DepartmentName='$department_name' AND ";

    $appendString = str_lreplace("AND","",$appendString);
    // create the statement
    $searchStatement = "select * from Item where $appendString";

    $result = mysql_query($searchStatement);
    $message = "";

    if(!$result) {
        $message = "Error in updating Item: $item_number: ". mysql_error();
    } else {
        $message = "Data for Item: $item_number.";
    }

    return $result;

  }

  function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
  {
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
  }

  function connect_to_db($server, $username, $pwd, $dbname) {
    $conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $pwd);
    if(!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
    }
    $dbh = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$dbh) {
        echo "Unable to select " .$dbname. ": " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: *"I'm still very new to PHP"* - You shouldn't be working/learning with a deprecated mysql api. You're probably going to end up recoding everything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Its a school project and its all were given.

Comment: schools really need to step out of the dino age lol

Comment: If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard how should I do it correctly so the 2nd php segment runs the query?